# Do Samsung devices treat FragmentTransactions differently than other devices?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction, samsung-touchwiz

I have been trying to solve a problem that is driving me nuts for ages. I have an app with one Activity that shows different screens by dynamic fragment exchange, ie the usual

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragementContainer, new SomeFragment()).commit();
```

This works great on my Nexus 4, Nexus 5, Nexus 7 2012, Nexus 7 2013, Moto G 1st gen etc. Mostly everything except Samsung devices (SGS5, SGS6). On these devices, sometimes (rarely, but not rarely enough) the **replace()** call seems to be misinterpreted as an **add()** call and the new fragment appears on top of the previous one.

I have tried replicating the bug but there doesn't seem to be any pattern to it. Since I get no error messages anywhere, I can't really troubleshoot it.

Comment: I've seen a lot of bizarre, intermittent bugs on Samsung devices.  Stuff like crashes due to a missing permission that the app clearly does have, else it would have crashed the other 999 out of 1000 times.  My gut instinct says they're over-optimizing for their multi-core CPUs and running into race conditions.

Comment: Yeah this is probably a Samsung thing. Try using `remove()` and `add()` instead of `replace()`.

Comment: @Lamorak: I thought about it but the problem with that approach is that I have to know which fragment was previously loaded so that I can call remove() on that, which means a lot of mess with if-statements in the code that I'd like to avoid.

Comment: I don't understand. Your statement "...misinterpreted as an add() call and the new fragment appears on top of the previous one.". Isn't replace() suppose to show the new fragment on top of previous?

Comment: As far as I know, a replace() call first removes the previous fragment and then adds the new one, which means that the old fragment does not exist behind the new one.

Comment: Yes, [`replace()` docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace%28int,%20android.support.v4.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String%29) state that it actually is similar to `remove()` and `add()`.

Comment: @Antonis427, Technically replace() does not remove the previous fragment. The document states replace does "Replace an existing fragment that was added to a container", from link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace(int, android.app.Fragment, java.lang.String). So this states it removes the fragment using the container view ID. This info may give you a hint on what to do. I normally use replace() with the same container ID, and never manage my own fragments. I use AddtoBackStack() for that.

Answer (score 3):

This is the why I always use support libraries. Source code is within your project and has not been modified by third parties. Are you already using support package?

Comment: I'm using the standard platform fragments, so no support package ones.

Comment: Switching to support fragments might help you as well.

Comment: @Lamorak: I'm sure it'll give me the standard behavior, de-Samsunged. I tried your method, if that doesn't work I'll use support fragments.

Comment: @Antonis427 have you replaced the Fragment with the one provided by the support library? Are you still getting the issue? If not, can you accept the answer please?

Answer (score 1):

This might very well be caused by some Samsung "optimizations". The only thing I can advise is to use `remove()` and `add()` instead of `replace()`. The implementation within `FragmentTransaction` is different so there is a chance this will behave differently.

You can actually remove the fragment easily because it has the same id as the container. Try this:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

Fragment oldFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.container);
if (oldFragment != null) transaction.remove(oldFragment);

transaction.add(R.id.container, new Fragment(), "tag").commit();
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and the idea of using the findFragmentById() method, which I never thought of using! I tried it, let's see what happens!